# Why is my atmega32u4 not showing up as a USB device

Tags: pcb, usb, pcb-assembly, atmega32u4

I have an atmega32u4 as part of a PCB that I designed.  The atmega32u4 comes with a USB bootloader and so I should just be able to plug it into my USB port and have it show up as a device.  It doesn't show up as a device, so clearly there is something wrong.

According to this website: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/usb-connector-pinout if my USB B has VCC =~5 V, D- =0 V, D+ = 3.3 V, then the computer should read that there is a USB device present.  I have measured that this is the case with a voltage probe (although D+ is only 3.14 V which I doubt is the problem).

Regardless of whether the board is functioning properly or not, if I'm measuring those values on the USB B pins, shouldn't my computer be recognizing that there is a USB device present?

Edit: 
I've checked the signal with an oscilloscope and there is definitely a signal on the D+ line [image]

note that the signal has a period of almost a second, which is weird.  It sometimes stays as that exact signal, but if I've just unplugged and replugged the USB connection it will do something interesting like this:
[image]

So I think that means my computer is at least trying to communicate with it and failing, but I don't know what to do with that information.

There are sometimes very short-width signals as can be seen at the beginning of the second picture.  I'm not sure why there are pulses that are so short and pulses that take almost a second.  Is one of those my computer and one of those the microcontroller?

Second edit:
So I'm starting to think that I just don't understand what is supposed to happen when I plug my board in.  I was under the impression that since the board comes with a USB bootloader I could plug it into my computer and immediately see it as a USB device, and also see it as an available port in the Arduino IDE.  Is this the case?

Comment: Not necessarily, usually the host will ping the device when it thinks the device is there. If the device replies then stuff starts to happen. If the device does not reply, then nothing happens. Are you sure that the uC is powering up and that all its USB requirements are met? Usually, there is a power pin that connecting USB triggers the device to know that enumiration is coming.

Comment: The USB boot loader is only loaded in devices with an external XTAL, which means it is only on the ATMEGA32U4-AU and ATMEGA32U4RC-AU parts. Which one specifically did you use? If you didn't use any of those, and you don't have firmware on there that initializes the USB stack, the computer can't query the device and get back an enumeration on the port.

Comment: I'm using this ATMEGA32U4-AUR  https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/ATMEGA32U4-AUR/ATMEGA32U4-AURCT-ND/3440960 which says it comes with a DFU USB bootloader

Comment: Have you connected the HWB (Bootloader entry) pin to GND?

Comment: HWB is pin 33 (PE2) which must be connected to ground and the reset signal pulsed low then high to enter the bootloader

Comment: I do not have pin 33 connected to anything it seems.

Comment: But I just checked the voltage from pin 33 to ground and it is always 0, including during reset

Comment: When you probe it, it will be weakly to GND due to the 1M scope probe. When you aren't probing it, it will float to some unknown voltage. Try connecting it to GND directly and while grounded reset the MCU at plug in to the USB.

Comment: What you see is the host trying to USB_RESET the bus asserting D- and D+ low for 50-200ms. Then the host should start SOF packets at precise 1 ms interval, and then it should issue several USB packets in attempt to enumerate the device. It doesn't look like it is doing this. This is a function of healthy USB host (your PC I guess), and it doesn't depend on your device. Could it be a chance that you swap D+ and D- by accident?